# Falha ao passar propriedade de uma entidade como parâmetro no MySqlCommand

Tags: c#, mysql

Tenho o seguinte código em minha aplicação:

```
public Usuario checkLogin(Usuario entity)
    {
        //return
        Usuario userEntity = new Usuario();

        connection = mysql.OpenConnection();
        try
        {
            MySqlCommand stm = new MySqlCommand();
            MySqlDataReader data;

            stm.CommandText = "CALL validaLogin(?login, ?senha)";
            stm.Connection = connection;
            stm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?login", entity.Login);
            stm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?senha", entity.Senha);

            var id = stm.ExecuteScalar();
            errorUtil.showCustomAlert(id.ToString());
        } catch(MySqlException ex)
        {
            errorUtil.showDBError(ex);
        } finally{
            connection.Close();
        }
        return userEntity;
    }
```

A função dele é basicamente receber um usuário e senha e efetuar a validação do login por meio do stored procedure `validaLogin`. Porém, ao passar o atributo `Login` do objeto `entity` a minha consulta simplesmente não retornada nada (necessariamente precisa retornar pois os dados que digito no form são idênticos aos salvos no MySQL).

Entretanto, caso eu substitua o atributo do objeto por uma `string` (conforme abaixo) obtenho sucesso em minha query.

```
stm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?login", "logindousuario");
stm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?senha", "senhadousuario");
```

Answer (score 1):

Usei o método `Trim()` para retirar o espaçamento do texto recuperado do `TextBox` e deu tudo certo. Problema resolvido!